# Passing Realm object as Retrofit 2 PUT request body

Tags: android, gson, retrofit, realm

I am trying to use RealmObject as a PUT message body content in Retrofit 2. I have implemented custom Gson with JsonSerializer and it works fine outside of Retrofit, but I am still not getting object data in request body. 
Gradle build for retrofit and gson:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Retrofit service:

```
public interface LogstashRetrofitService {
    @PUT(LOGSTASH_SERVER_PATH)
    Call<ResponseBody> putLogstashMessage(@Body LogstashMessage logstashMessage);
}
```

Building Retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(LOGSTASH_SERVER_HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(RealmObjectGsonBuilder.getRealmGson()))
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build();
logstashRetrofitService = retrofit.create(LogstashRetrofitService.class);
logstashRetrofitService.putLogstashMessage(logstashMessage).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {}
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {}
    });
```

Comment: *I am still not getting object data in request body.* what are you getting then?

Comment: may be it is not possible i am not 100% sure but you refer this link https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#what-is-the-difference-between-a-normal-java-object-and-a-realm-object

Comment: What status code are you getting?

Comment: @iAndroid yes, using Realm.copyFromRealm() solves the problem

Comment: Huh, I didn't know it creates a deep copy with the instance fields set. Cool!

Answer (score 7):

It's because GSON tries to serialize your object based on fields using reflection, but the Realm instance data is only accessible through the proxy getter setter methods.

See related open issue because GSON doesn't really care and therefore doesn't have config to use the getters/setters instead https://github.com/google/gson/issues/232

This is possible with Jackson or LoganSquare json parsers.

Or, you need to make an unmanaged copy of your RealmObject, which can be done with `realmObject.copyFromRealm()` which creates a deep copy of your class, detached from the Realm.